# Can't login after fresh installation

Tags: login

I recently installed a new distro called sidbang. I created a liveCD and ran it on my laptop, which worked fine. I then ran the installation script. I set a username, 'sam', and password, 'a' (this was to make sure that I wasn't simply mistyping my password - I will change it as soon as I get into my new operating system). When the installation was finished, I removed the liveCD and booted the operating system from my hard drive. It asks me for a username and password, which I enter. It then says that the login is incorrect.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Things I have tried:

1. Trying again

   - I thought that I may have mistyped my password during the installation, so I tried reinstalling and reselecting the password multiple times. This did not work
2. Default username and password

   - The default username and password that are advertised for LinuxBBQ are 'bbq' and 'bbq'. I wasn't able to log in using these credentials

Sorry about the wording and formatting of this question - my laptop is out of order and so I am using a device that I am not comfortable with to ask this question.

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: You can boot with the live cd, mount the hard-disk root, `chroot` to make the root on the hd the new root, and finnaly as root `passwd`. (this will reset the password to what ever you want, but is this solving the correct problem).

Comment: Thanks richard! That solved my problem. I'd like to accept your answer as correct, if you leave it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- boot with the live cd
- mount the hard-disk root: `mount /dev/???? /mnt`
- chroot to make the root on the hd the new root: `chroot /mnt`
- and finnaly as root run passwd: `sudo passwd sam`

This will reset the password to what ever you want, but is this solving the correct problem